# How to use Backgroundworker?

Tags: c#

I need to display a process bar when I start "cleanmgr". I search everywhere, there is a lot of code but nothing that helps me. Please help me.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Proc = new Process();
        Proc.SynchronizingObject = this;
        Proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Proc.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe");
        Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/Sagerun:100";
        Proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Proc.Start();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(Proc);
        int i = 0;
        Process[] Proc1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("cleanmgr.exe");
        i++;
        toolStripProgressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";

        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        if ((backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.ToString = true;
        }
```

Comment: Can you actually measure the progress of that process?  How can you display something to the user if you can't measure it?

Comment: At this moment, it is impossible for me to measure it, because it depends on the speed of the computer of the user. So I put a relative measure or ... It's a Windows Cleanup utility.

Comment: But, it has its own progress bar. Is it possible to synchronize it with my own bare?

Comment: How to get a value from a progress bar in an external application is a very different question and something you should research for yourself first.  Until then, the most appropriate option would be to set the `Style` of your own `ProgressBar` to `Marquee`, to indicate that something is happening but not where it's actually up to, because you don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, I could not find an answer to synchronize my progress bar with that of another progress bar software. I opt for another solution. I opted for events with "EventHandler".

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CenterToScreen();
        toolStripProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(BarAnimation);
        button2.Click += new EventHandler(BarAnimation);
        button3.Click += new EventHandler(BarAnimation);
        button4.Click += new EventHandler(BarAnimation);
    }
```

...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Proc = new Process();
        Proc.SynchronizingObject = this;
        Proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Proc.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe");
        Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/sagerun:100";
        Proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Proc.Start();
        Proc.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcExited);
```

...

```
    private void BarAnimation(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 1;
        toolStripProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    }

    private void ProcExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ProgressChanged` event to fire.

```
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
//Add the event to see the ProgressChanged
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
```

In the event you can work on the Progress Bar as you like.

```
void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```